# what's the best approach to do this in crystal report?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

what's the best approach to do this in crystal report ? i got 3 tables the Main table, the Sub table for the Main and another one is the item table for the Sub of the sub..it goes something like this..

```
MainTable - stored the main accounts.

idKey       Accnt           Amount
------------------------------------
01          Construction     1000.00
02          Maintenance       500.00


SubTable - this table where sub account for the main table stored.
         - the idkey from this table and main table is equal.

idKey    idSub   SubAccnt               Amount
-----------------------------------------
01          01   WatchTower             800.00
01          02   Level 9 Wall           200.00
02          03   Monthly Maintenance    500.00

itemTable - this table where the items of the sub table stored.
          - the idsub of this table and the SubTable is equal.

idSub       Items        Cost
-----------------------------------
01          Cement       100.00
01          Steel        100.00
01          Labor        400.00
02          Rocks        100.00
02          Labor        100.00
03          Labor        500.00
```

now i want the report to be look like this..

[image]

how to do this ? do i need a sub-report for this ? and how ? and using crystal report and VB.NET..glad for any help..tnx in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query might help u out

```
  Select MT.Accnt,ST.SubAccnt, ST.amount,sum(IT.cost) from MainTable MT
    inner join SubTable ST on ST.idKey=MT.idKey       
    inner join itemTable IT on IT.idSub=ST.idSub
    Group By MT.Accnt,ST.SubAccnt, ST.amount
```

Subreport is not required and For Balance you can achive in query or you can do it in report itself

add Group for MT.Accnt and add total for the same.

Comment: i'll try this out mate..tnx :)